# TensorFlow - Optimizing model parameters with gradient-free optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, optimization

I am defining a model in TensorFlow in which the output of the network is related to the ground truth through computations carried out in an external package.

Basically, my model looks something like this:

[image]

with the loss function defined in the following way:

```
Loss(y_out, y_true):
    y_pred = functionCalledFromExternalPackage(y_out)
    loss = mean_squared_error(y_pred, y_true)
    return loss
```

Of course, this means that I cannot use gradient-based optimizers to find the layers' weights, because there can be no gradient if the computations are executed outside of TensorFlow.
One option would be to implement `functionCalledFromExternalPackage` using `tf` functions, something that is somewhat cumbersome and undesirable in my situation.

So, I was wondering if there is any way to use gradient-free optimizers in the training process, something like particle swarm optimization, evolution strategies ecc...